# Can an app keep onto its root access permissions after the phone is turned off?

Tags: android, linux, root, su, superuser

My question is plain and simple. Can an app keep onto its root access permissions after the phone is turned off? Is there a way an app with root access can keep this permission and start running with this permission without asking for it again once the device is turned back on?

If so, how?

Comment: The user would have to tell the superuser app not to ask again for the dialog not to be shown, but you'll always have to request `su` regardless.

Comment: @KaneO'Riley Hello Kane! Thanks for your answer! If it is okay, I'd like to ask just one more thing about this case. So its request can be set to auto-grant by superuser app, but it can not run at boot with a `su` access. I got it until here. But can an app with `su` access create a backdoor for itself that will grant it `su` without getting SuperSU(or any other su app) involved?

Comment: The only way you could do that is to create your own superuser daemon that auto grants access, or via an init script, but that is way outside the scope of this post and should be asked in a new question.

Comment: @KaneO'Riley Agreed. Weird. There are a lot of spy app companies that claim their apps can keep on spying on root level even after a reboot. If only they weren't so expensive I'd really want to test that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user would have to tell the superuser app not to ask again for the dialog not to be shown, but you'll always have to request `su` in the shell process you create regardless.